# How to prove an Isomorphism for a G/N (N normal) to H subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group and let $N \subseteq  G$ be a normal subgroup. Suppose there is a subgroup $H \subseteq G$ such that:

$$ HN= G $$

$$ H \cap  N = \{e \} $$

Prove tat H is a system of representatives for the cosets of N in G, and that $ G/N \cong H$.

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the second isomorphism theorem for groups?

Comment: Write down the only homomorphism $H\to G/N$ that you can think of. Show form the first property that it is onto. Show from the second property that it has trivial kernel.

Comment: @M.Wang Yes I am familiar with that!

Comment: @M.Wang But how would you use that Theorem

Answer (score 0):

It's a direct application of the second isomorphism theorem. It states:

Let $G$ be a subgroup, $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $H/{H \cap N} \cong HN/N$. This isomorphism is given by sending $h(H \cap N)$ to $hN$.

In your case, $H \cap N$ is trivial, so $H/{H \cap N}=H$ and since $HN = G$, $HN/N = G/N$. So

$$H/{H \cap N} = H \cong HN/N = G/N, \ h \mapsto hN.$$